# ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit - capturing unhandled exceptions?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I inherited an ASP.NET (.NET 4.7.2) application. It has Elastic rigged-up (via the Javascript API) to capture APM data and errors from the front-end.

The top offending errors in Elastic for months now have been:

1. Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request timed out.
2. Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server.  The status code returned from the server was:  404 (but sometimes it will say 503).

Both refer to ScriptResource.axd as being the "culprit".

On the one hand, it sure would be nice if I could find out exactly WHAT resource or URL was being requested... as well as which page in my app is doing the requesting.... when such an error occurs.

But I'm at the point now where... as an alternative, I'd just be happy to change these from being unhandled exceptions to handled ones.  (I don't think our users are actually having any serious issues from these.  The major page for this app is one that updates a couple of key update panels once every 8 seconds.  So, occasional failures of those requests are somewhat expected.  Users would have already raised hell if something major was going on.)

I'd much rather see any errors in Elastic that are coming from our own Javascript code than from the Ajax Control Toolkit.

So, does anyone know how I might capture these?

Comment: It will be in your browser's DevTools' Network tab.

Comment: ...and when you're debugging, open Debug > Exceptions and ensure the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" is checked (not partially) and "Just My Code" (under Tools > Options > Debugging) is disabled. That way VS will break at the point of a thrown exception - though note that WebForms _loves_ to throw exceptions for non-exceptional errors (e.g. HTTP 404) so watch out.

Comment: Hum, is that server time out issue limited to a particular page? I see that message all the time on a page that uses the ajaxtoolkit AjaxFileUpload control.

Comment: By "capture", I mean capture and deal with them at the code level.   I don't know how to actually recreate the errors myself in the browser.  Left idle on that once-every-8-second-refresh, I simply don't see them.  (Perhaps, over several hours, one might appear. Not sure)   

I have no idea what page is actually giving the error, but simply based on how I know people use the application, that 8 second data refresh page is the most-likely-culprit.

Again, no users have reported these. I haven't seen these myself.  Elastic is reporting them via a Javascript APM client loaded into every page.

Answer (score 0):

I THINK I've finally found the right information (though some of these pages are from 2008).  How to basically add a custom error handler to the Script Manager:

[Script Manager 4.5 handling errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709041/script-manager-4-5-handling-errors)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59a34e36-f80b-4344-a793-8ea2ce21abe2/ajax-exception-handling?forum=aspdotnetajax

[Handle Asynch error messages with ScriptManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958158/handle-asynch-error-messages-with-scriptmanager)

https://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2010/02/03/Unhide-Exceptions-Hidden-By-AJAX.aspx

Looks like I should be able to either bury the exceptions... or get more details on them and pass them on through to get thrown to Elastic.

I think my biggest hurdle right now would be to actually try to recreate these errors myself (preferably in a non-prod environment).   But I guess I'll figure that out somehow.

Thanks!